# Advice on using .NET to generate semantic html

Tags: .net, html, accessibility, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've just started working on a project which a) uses .NET and a fair bit of AJAX, and b) must comply to AA accessibility standards.

.NET AJAX toolkit is ideal in one sense - it provides a non-javascript fallback for each bit of javascript interactivity - but equally it fails badly as the html generated by the controls is often completely unsemantic (eg I can't see a way to make the accordion control use ul/ol tags instead of divs).

Are there any approaches that can make use of the positive aspects of the toolkit, while minimising the negative effect of the poor html?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check ASP.NET MVC, which is a new approach in ASP.NET arena to create web applications.

That's controlling what's going to render and less auto-generated code, so I believe this is your way to go, isn't it?

Comment: ASP.Net MVC isn't an AJAX tool/technology. You may want to re-read the question again and change/remove your answer.

Comment: Read your question. You want ASP.NET to provide you a way to customize your markup, and ASP.NET doesn't have it. So, what? :) Oh, and you'll want to remove the negative vote, because my answer just answers "no, actual Web Forms doesn't have what you want"... Ok thanks.

Comment: I didn't down vote you and it's not my question. Just thought you should make your answer appropriate for the question.

Comment: Having looked into this, it turns out that much of ajax toolkit's functionality depends on the way standard .NET handles forms, and while you can use the toolkit js libraries with .net mvc, you can't use the .net controls, so you lose the close coupling with the server side classes that makes the no-javascript fallback so smooth. So to sum up, using mvc unfortunately throws the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: @jflay oh, well, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @wheresrhys I'm not meaning using AJAX Control Toolkit or whatever related to Web Forms. I was suggesting if you need a very customized markup, Web Forms isn't your solution, or you can use it, but creating controls from scratch, which is a big effort.

Answer (score 0):

While I see what you are getting at with the semantics of ol/ul vs div, the use of a div does not constitute "poor html".  It's fairly proper to use the div for any block (styled or otherwise) inside of a HTML page.

To get to your question, about the only thing I can think of is for you to make your own controls and control the HTML rendering of the control **OR** you might be able to make custom versions of the controls in the kit (ex: accordion) and then override the rendering of the control. This would be a lot of work and really in my view unnecessary.

**ADDITIONAL RESOURCES**

[WCAG Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/)

[WCAG 2.0 Quick Reference](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/Overview.php)

Comment: From the standpoint of accessibility, overuse of divs IS certainly poor html. A site using divs where ul/ol should be used would fail accessibility guidelines (level 2 certainly, and maybe even level 1 depending on how you interpret the specification). Just because using divs for any block is widespread it doesn't mean it's correct to do so.

Comment: Is there any specific checkpoint that you are referring to?  Looking it over I see nothing denoting the specific use of ol/ul vs div, but I could be missing it.

Comment: Point 1.3.1 http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-programmatic.html. On double-checking, it's been moved to the lowest level, A, guidelines - it was an AA guideline only up until 2008. Or H48 http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20101014/H48 to be more specific to ol/ul use

Comment: H48 talks about how you should use ol/ul/dl (when you use it), but it does not state that you have to use those tags.  It even says in the description "Although the use of this markup can make lists more readable, not all lists need markup.". It goes on to give an example, but not an exhaustive listing of when not to use those tags.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a pain in the butt on this point, just trying to understand where you are coming from. Regardless, if you want to do this, then you will have to do some custom/inherited controls.

Comment: But after saying not all lists need markup it does then give the example of a comma separated list within a sentence, where using list markup would break other W3C specifications (not allowed to put a ul inside a p tag). However, if the decision to not use semantic markup is based on the technology used, rather than on careful consideration of the nature of the content, then I doubt any expert would give that page a pass mark.

It is starting to look like going to the effort of writing a custom control is what we'll have to do as accessibility is a high priority for the site.